# Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.Types when calling ContactZendeskActivity

Tags: android, retrofit, zendesk

I have integrated ZenDesk in my app but when calling ContactZendeskActivity for ticket creation app crashed. Log cat is attached below. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':CircularImageView')
    compile project(':CircularImageCropper')
    compile project(':SwipeLayout')
    compile project(':DragNDropLib')
    compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.5.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.Types
>                                                                   at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(RestMethodInfo.java:286)
>                                                                   at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.(RestMethodInfo.java:97)
>                                                                   at retrofit.RestAdapter.getMethodInfo(RestAdapter.java:213)
>                                                                   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:236)
>                                                                   at $Proxy1.getSettings(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl.ZendeskSdkSettingsService.getSettings(ZendeskSdkSettingsService.java:37)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl.ZendeskSdkSettingsProvider.getSettings(ZendeskSdkSettingsProvider.java:57)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl.ZendeskBaseProvider.getSdkSettings(ZendeskBaseProvider.java:92)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl.ZendeskSettingsHelper.loadSetting(ZendeskSettingsHelper.java:28)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskFragment.preloadSettingsAndInit(ContactZendeskFragment.java:237)
>                                                                   at com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.ui.ContactZendeskFragment.onCreateView(ContactZendeskFragment.java:223)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
>                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
>                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
>                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please attach the relevant Retrofit interface code, and how you are building retrofit too

Comment: It is using inside ZenDesk. I have not added any code for Retrofit  in my app

Comment: then you prolly need to add retrofit as a dependency to your project

Comment: It is working fine in android 5.0 and above

Comment: Then its most definitely a multi-dexing issue

Comment: How can I fix it.Can you help me

Comment: Search on google about how to enable multi dex for android and make sure you want it and know what you are doing before enabling it, the quick fix here most probably would be to add the dependency to retrofit in your project directly

Comment: I have already enable multiDex and added dependency also. I will check by adding the retrofit dependency

Comment: it is not working after adding the retrofit dependency

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding project.

Comment: What version of Retrofit do you have added? The Zendesk SDK need v1.9.0. Make sure to use at least v2.0.0-beta3 if you want to use Retrofit 2 in your project.

Comment: @Sebastian Added Retrofit version  is 1.9.0.

Comment: @Sebastian after adding compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3' getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.RestMethodInfo$RequestType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed by adding MultiDex.install(this); in my application class as below. No need to add retrofit dependency in this case.

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);
}
```